# Linking to assets without the asset helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way I can link to an asset in my public folder without having to use the AssetHelper? I have a .swf flash player that I am trying to embed in one of my views but I cannot tell the javascript to include it without a valid path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you reference it directly? If you have a file foo.swf in your public folder, you can refer to it as '/foo.swf'. I'm not sure what javascript embedding you're using, but if it's [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) it would look something like:

```
swfobject.embedSWF('/foo.swf', ... )
```